# How to focus on Jwplayer after loading the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jwplayer

Once user load our page we wanna use the short cuts of Jwplayer. Right now for using the short cuts user has to do one of the following 2 things.

1. User need to use tab until he reach on Jwplayer.
2. Click two times on player.

Is there any way to do it through javascript, so once user reach on page then he can use the short cuts like youtube.

Short cuts mean if user press space key then video should play and vice versa and using arrow video should forward and backward.

For example:- http://tv.jwplayer.com/video/qISnTr5d/1oPgneTb
this is Jwplayer site. Above short cuts either you need to click 2 times on video or you have to press tab until you reach on video.

Comment: Without looking at your code/example of the problem it will be really hard to help

Comment: Updated the question @Dekel

Comment: I opened the link, clicked on the "play" button, and the video just got played. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I am taking about the short cuts. if you will press space bar then video will not play until you will click inside player. and once you will click inside player  after play the video then short cuts will start

Answer (score 1):

Just call `focus` method of appropriate video element. Like `document.querySelector("video").focus()` (you should use appropriate selector if you have more than one video element on the page). Call it after video element is created.

Comment: In general thats correct, but it will be nice to see a working example (to make sure that the focus actually does the work).

Comment: I have checked it on the provided page (using browser dev console). I pressed space after page load - it didn't start the video. After that I executed this code and pressed space again and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  Simply calling focus() worked for me on Firefox, but not Chrome.

I wound up using the advice on this page (click the "Here's a workaround" link and view source): https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/questions/16959756-player-loses-focus-after-clicking-on-the-controlbar

Specifically, the new code is an .on() added at the end of setup().  There are two places where jwplayer() is used.  If you have more than one player on the page, you will need to make it more specific like jwplayer("container")

```
jwplayer("container").setup({
    // usual setup content here
}).on('ready',function(){
    // This will set the player in focus when it's ready
    jwplayer().getContainer().focus();
    // This will set focus back to the player when the controls are pressed
    var controls = document.getElementsByClassName("jw-controls")[0];
    controls.addEventListener("click", function(){
        console.log("click controls");
        setTimeout(function(){
            jwplayer().getContainer().focus();
        },200);
    });
});
```